# Randomly got this error on my react app => TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

My React app was working fine then I randomly got this error:
[image]

The below code was working fine but now it's showing the above error. I am unable to find what has gone wrong. Please help

```
import RestaurantCard from "./RestaurantCard";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Shimmer from "./Shimmer";
import { RESTAURANT_FETCH_API_LINK } from "../utils/constants";

const Body = () => {

  const [dataToRender, _setDataToRender] = useState([]);
  const [filterdData, _setFilterdData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  },[]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(RESTAURANT_FETCH_API_LINK); // fetch() --> returns a Promise

    const dataJSON = await data.json();

    const valueToRender =
      dataJSON?.data?.cards[4]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants;
    _setDataToRender(valueToRender);
    _setFilterdData(valueToRender);
  };

  return dataToRender.length === 0 ? (
    <Shimmer />
  ) : (
    <div className="body">
      <div className="res-container">
        {filterdData?.map((resEle) => {
          return (
            <RestaurantCard resObejectData={resEle} key={resEle.info.id} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

I want to show the user a Shimmer UI (i.e. `<Shimmer />`) till the data fetching of all restaurants is completed.

Comment: Check the value of `valueToRender`. It is almost certainly `undefined`. The response from your `fetch` call probably does not look the way you expect it does

Comment: @Andrew Man I just added `console.log(valueToRender)` before `_setDataToRender(valueToRender);`  and saw that the response to `fetch` was actually working fine. But suddenly app got refreshed and is working fine now. I am totally confused

Comment: Just change the line to `return ((dataToRender?.length ?? 0) === 0 ? (` or `const valueToRender =
      dataJSON?.data?.cards[4]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants ?? [];` You've got to deal with the result when `?.` comes out null or undefined.

Comment: @HereticMonkey my code is working fine now, but will definitely try what you have mentioned. Thanks